# Postgres SQLSTATE[42725]: Ambiguous function

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Estou tentando executar o update a seguir utilizando Postgres mas estou me deparando com a mensagem a seguir. Alguém conhece uma forma de resolver?

> "SQLSTATE[42725]: Ambiguous function: 7 ERRO: operador não é único:
>   unknown - unknown"

```
UPDATE produto.categoria_departamento SET left_categoria = (left_categoria + ".$width.") WHERE (left_categoria >= CASE WHEN ".$destino." > ".$right." THEN  ".$destino." - ".$width." ELSE ".$destino." END) AND (parent = ".$parent." OR fk_codigo_categoria = ".$parent.")
```

Quando dou echo na sql obtenho: `UPDATE produto.categoria_departamento SET left_categoria = (left_categoria + 10) WHERE (left_categoria >= CASE WHEN 2 > 27 THEN  2 - 10 ELSE 2 END) AND (parent = 46 OR fk_codigo_categoria = 46)`

Comment: Desconfio que o erro esteja aqui `".$destino." - ".$width."` ambas são ints?

Comment: sim, todas as variaveis

Comment: Poderia dar um echo nessa sql e colocar na pergunta? se puder colocar o pg_query() dela tbm seria bom.

Comment: QUando vc copia e cola essa query no pgAdmin aparece mais alguma descrição sobre o erro? tente assim `".$destino."::int - ".$width."::int `

Comment: O procedimento da minha resposta funcinou para o seu caso?

Answer (score 2):

Pessoal estou utilizando Laravel 5 e a minha query era:

```
DB::update("UPDATE bemed_produto.categoria_departamento SET left_categoria = (left_categoria + ?) WHERE left_categoria >= (CASE WHEN ? > ? THEN  ? - ?  ELSE ? END) AND (parent = ? OR fk_codigo_categoria = ?)", [$width, $destino, $right, $destino, $width, $width, $parent, $parent ]);
```

consegui resolver concatenando as variáveis  direto ao invés de utilizar **?**.

Answer (score 2):

Eu consegui simular o erro e obter o mesmo SQL state `42725`, por padrão o laravel utiliza prepared statements não emulados, o que driver do PDO faz é enviar todos os valores como strings, por isso acontece o erro o postgres esperam inteiros na sua consulta porém strings são passadas.

O erro gerado é:

> ERRO: operador não é único: unknown - unknown
>
> SQL state: 42725
>
> Hint: Não pôde escolher um operador que se enquadra melhor. Você precisa adicionar conversões de tipo explícitas.

### Simulção do erro

[Exemplo - sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/79847/5)

Para simular o erro basta uma consulta bem simples,

Para obter o erro sem uma consulta preparada, o teste é feito direto no pgAdmin ou phpPgAdmin com essa consulta ou similiar(outros operadores)

```
SELECT '1'- '1'
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $options = array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false);
    $db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=postgres user=usuario password=senha', $options);

    $sql = "SELECT ? + ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(10,5));
    $res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($res);
```

### Solução

Mudar a opção `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` para `true`, essa configuração está definida na classe `Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector` e `PostgresConnector` herda ela. [No laravel5.1](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php#L24), abra as pastas`laravel\framework\src\illuminate\database\connectors`.

Configuração original:

```
protected $options = [
    PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_NATURAL,
    PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];
```

ou faça os respectivos cast(tipar) nos placeholders, como abaixo.

```
$sql = 'select ?::int - ?::int as resultado';

//teste do pgAdmin

SELECT '10'::int - '5'::int as resultado';
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que você colocou do seu select está faltando fechar o ultimo parenteses.

Atual:

```
UPDATE produto.categoria_departamento SET left_categoria = (left_categoria + 
10) WHERE (left_categoria >= CASE WHEN 2 > 27 THEN  2 - 10 ELSE 2 END) AND 
(parent = 46 OR fk_codigo_categoria = 46
```

Fechando parentes:

```
UPDATE produto.categoria_departamento SET left_categoria = (left_categoria + 
10) WHERE (left_categoria >= CASE WHEN 2 > 27 THEN  2 - 10 ELSE 2 END) AND 
(parent = 46 OR fk_codigo_categoria = 46) -- <<<<
```

Isso resolve seu problema?

Comment: Foi na hora de copiar aqui que acabei nao pegando o parenteses